# Existe formulário MDI para GTK 3 ou 2 em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, gtk, mdi

Existe uma classe que define um formulário MDI no Ruby GTK 2 ou 3, semelhante ao encontrado em outras linguagens como Delphi, C#, VB etc.?

Obs: MDI é aquele formulário para aplicações desktop que uma janela é aberta dentro de outra, ou seja, fica no escopo da janela principal, não saindo fora dela.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link aqui: http://zetcode.com/gui/rubygtk/ - Acredito que seja o que você procura.